# Need help with cname entries, wrt amazon S3

Tags: domain-name, amazon-s3, cname-record

I want to host my images on Amazon S3. So I created a bucket by the name `images.foo.com` and added a CNAME entry with the record host as `images.foo.com` and a record answer as `s3.amazonaws.com`.

There is a file in the bucket named image.jpg, under a folder named images. which I can access at `images.foo.com.s3.amazonaws.com/images/image.jpg` I cant access the same from `images.foo.com/images/image.jpg`

I also changed the record answer to `s3.amazonaws.com/images.foo.com/`, but that also doesnt work. What am I missing?

Thanks.

EDIT, AFTER THE ANSWER: Just read these pages:

http://carltonbale.com/how-to-alias-a-domain-name-or-sub-domain-to-amazon-s3

http://www.wrichards.com/blog/2009/02/customize-your-amazon-s3-url/comment-page-1/#comment-135

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Point your `images.foo.com` CNAME at `images.foo.com.s3.amazonaws.com`, the full name you want it to be an alias for. (Think 'CNAME == symlink'.)

Your first try just points to `s3.amazonaws.com`, which isn't what you want, and the second makes no sense, since slashes aren't valid in domain names (and also you have the parts backwards).

Comment: yeah, i just saw a few pages, that said the same. thanks for the answer :)